# What does "perceptive" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> I became his first love and the mother of his first child and, as
>   such, I have a unique **perceptive** to share on this man who has
>   fascinated the world.

It is taken from the NOTE TO THE READER section of the book *The Bite in the Apple* by Chrisann Brennan.

I'm unable to understand the usage of the word perceptive in this context. I think it could be a typo(perhaps should be the word perspective?) by the author. However, I've seen such usage of perceptive over and over again in the same book so I'm even more confused.

Comment: How are you reading the book? Is it by any chance from an OCR-scanned source? Or possibly an unedited version? _Perceptive_ does not make any sense here to me, either—it has to be a typo for _perspective_ (which makes perfect sense), or possibly the writer just doesn’t know the difference between _perceptive_ and _perspective_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Could also possibly be ***perception***.

Comment: As I suspected: I just downloaded a sample of the book through iTunes (oh the irony!), and that sample does indeed have **perspective**, rather than _perceptive_, as expected.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: As I was reading your last comment, I was hoping you'd end it with "... **perspective**, rather than *perceptive*, as excepted".

Comment: @JohnY Erm, you lost me there, I’m afraid … that _is_ exactly how the comment ends..?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Look more carefully at the respective last words.

Comment: Ah! I see it now. :-D

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I was reading the physical book bought from Chapters. Thanks for downloading the book to make sure it is perspective now. They must have corrected the typo in the electronic version(but not the physical one yet)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply a mistake (typographical error or otherwise). It should be *perspective* instead of *perceptive*.

Comment: As Janus has said; I agree with him that it's too obvious to merit an 'answer'.